# Mysql Insert On Partition Takes Too Long With InnoDB Default Settings

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-5.5

I have a table partitioned by month and this table has 1.5M rows, for making queries it touches the correct partition and the query runs really fast. I've made my partition on this table because everyday people makes batch insert and everyday this table is growing up, moreover than making batch inserts, we use an app for crud operations and my problems is on insert rows, each insert is taking more than 5segs. I have tracked what's wrong on my process-list and I can see all my inserts are waiting for something, and reminds me when I used to have this table on MyIsam (actually is on Innodb). I'd like to know how can I increment speediness for insert operations on a partition table when they use the web application (or not using batch insert).

```
My table is on **Mysql 5.1**
Operative System: Debian
InnoDB Setup by Default (I have not made any changes on my.cnf), so any suggestion would be fine.
I have 4G available on free memory according free -g command on Debian.

 mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 8388608    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 2097152000 |
| innodb_log_buffer_size  | 1048576    |
| join_buffer_size        | 131072     |
| key_buffer_size         | 16777216   |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size | 8388608    |
| net_buffer_length       | 16384      |
| preload_buffer_size     | 32768      |
| read_buffer_size        | 131072     |
| read_rnd_buffer_size    | 262144     |
| sort_buffer_size        | 2097144    |
| sql_buffer_result       | OFF        |
+-------------------------+------------+
12 rows in set
```

The last thing I did was increment Innodb_buffer_pool_size to 2000MB and my server got slower.

Comment: Please add your mysql process list information so we can see the wait, add data model (relevant part), mysql config.

Comment: "...waiting for something..." then you need to find out what that something is. You will be able to see it in your slow query log.

Comment: The delay is just on the insert, all those inserts stay long. I have read on an article by Giuseppe Maxia that Partition a Table will lock the partition for each insertion. Id like to know if are there a way to improve this performance with no using an external table to then load to partition table(because that way won't be OLTP).

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  What is "5segs"?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'`.  How much RAM do you have?  How many rows are being inserted when it is "too slow"?

Comment: Hi Rick, Innodb buffer pool size is 1000MB and i have extended it to 2500MB and making that changes it become slower. I have updated my question upside so that you could see what show variables like '%buffer%' shows.